# Inputting the Nth Number of a sequence into Scrapy Start URL's

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looking for a shorthand way to input the Nth term of a sequence into Scrapy start URL's. For exampe, this is the longer version for adding the 24th:

```
   start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/us/shopping?items=24' ,
                 'https://www.example.com/us/shopping?items=48' ,
                 'https://www.example.com/us/shopping?items=72']
```

I've found that URL patterns such as these are common for ecommerce websites. For every number in sequence the following works well, however I've been unable to change it for the Nth number:

```
start_urls = (
    "https://www.example.com/us/shopping?items=%s" % page for page in xrange(0,20)
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the Nth number? What is your expected output?

Comment: The start URL's follow a set pattern, where a single number changes, in the example above it's 24,48,72,96 and so on. This is at the end of the URL in this case. I wish to know how to add this number sequence to the start URL's. Like xrange but only for the 24th number each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument in `xrange` allows you to provide a `step` of how much to increment it by.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
start_urls = [
    "https://www.example.com/us/shopping?items=%s" % page for page in xrange(24, 73, 24)
]
```

The code above will generate the same list you gave in the example.

The first argument (24) is where to start, the second argument (73) is where to stop (exclusive, so 73 to stop on 72) and the third argument (24) tells xrange how much to increment it by.